# Implementing Account abstraction in Hyperledger besu

Tags: account, abstraction, hyperledger-besu

I am implementeing account abstraction in Hyperledger besu network. I am not using bundler as of now, directly interacting with the entrypoint contract. But transactions are reverting with error "Transaction reverted".

besu version: besu/v23.10.3/linux-x86_64/openjdk-java-21

configFile.json

```
{
  "genesis": {
    "config":{
    "chainId": 17778,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleFixBlock": 0,
    "istanbulBlock": 0,
    "muirGlacierBlock": 0,
    "berlinBlock": 0,
    "londonBlock": 0,
    "zeroBaseFee": true,
    "ibft2": {
      "blockperiodseconds": 5,
      "epochlength": 30000,
      "requesttimeoutseconds": 10,
      "blockreward": "0x0"
     }
    },
    nonce": "0x0",
    "timestamp": "0x58ee40ba",
    "gasLimit": "0x47b760",
    "difficulty": "0x1",
    "mixHash": "0x63746963616c2062797a616e74696e65206661756c7420746f6c6572616e6365",
    "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "alloc": {
      "fe3b557e8fb62b89f4916b721be55ceb828dbd73": {
        "balance": "0xad78ebc5ac6200000"
      },
      "627306090abaB3A6e1400e9345bC60c78a8BEf57": {
        "balance": "90000000000000000000000"
      },
      "f17f52151EbEF6C7334FAD080c5704D77216b732": {
        "balance": "90000000000000000000000"
      }
    },
   "baseFeePerGas":"0x000000174876E800"
  },
  "blockchain": {
    "nodes": {
      "generate": true,
      "count": 4
    }
  }
}
```

I have changed the config file multiple times, but couldnt figure out the issue. I feel the issue is with network config as the similar scenario is working with mumbai and fuji networks